# Replacement battery for Cygolite Milion light?

Tags: headlights, battery

I have a Cygolite Milion 200 light purchased in 2010. Its battery is taking a long while to charge these days.

I wrote to Cygolite, and they say they don't have a replacement battery for it.

The Expilion battery looks to have the same form factor.

Does anyone know definitively that the Expilion battery fits, or does not fit, the Milion?

Comment: Not a dupe, but related info at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25454/

Comment: Visit a local battery store.

Comment: A large portion of the cost of an LED bike light is in the battery.  To be honest it's not worth trying to replace the battery in what is by todays standards a very low powered light.
You can probably buy something brighter, with a longer run time for the same cost as it would be to repair your current light.

Comment: Expilion's are much higher output and should not be used in the older Milion lights, they are not made to push the additional power that would be generated. Cygolites have gone down in cost even for much higher lumen outputs. I would play it safe and purchase a new light as yours has already had a good life of 9 years.

Comment: @Nate W higher output wont make a difference, for example a 3w LED will be same power regardless of power, the only factoring difference will be run time.

Comment: The chances are it uses a standard 18650 cell, if the OP is prepared to strip the light down the cell should have the relevant info needed for a replacement. If the OP is confident in soldering tabs onto the positive / negative of the cell it's a straightforward job. Replacing the cell with a higher amperage cell will produce more run time, obviously a downside will be charging time increases.

Answer (score 3):

I found the model number for the Milion battery via a search on the Wayback Machine. It's 426-44LN, which is different than the Expilion battery.

Comment: The model number may well be different, but that doesn't rule out the specifications being the same, or so close it can be adapted. If you edit all the details you've got into the original question, perhaps with photos of any labelling on the batteries, it might be possible to work this out.